# Почему один и тот же ключ ассоциирован со всеми значениями?

Tags: java, дата

Почему со всеми значениями карты map ассоциируется последний ключ?

Каждый раз `dataCollections.toString()` присваивает разные ключи соответственно разным element в карте map. При этом если потом вывести map на консоль, со всеми значение element будет ассоциирован последний ключ, последнее значение, возвращаемое методом `dataCollections.toString()`

```
    Map<String, Element> map = new TreeMap<String, Element>();
    Calendar firstDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsNumber; i++) {
        firstDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i * 110);
        // Создаю элемент, присваиваю его полю birthDate firstDate
        Element element = new Element(firstDate, random.nextInt(2000));
        // метод dataCollections.toString приводит аргумент типа Calendar 
        // к строке специального формата
        map.put(dataCollections.toString(element.getBirthDate), element); 
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Так ведь вы в каждый элемент передаете один и тот же объект Calendar. Вот он в них один и тот же и лежит...

Дело в том, что Calendar - изменяемый тип. Ваша строка `firstDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i * 110);` не создает новый объект, а меняет существующий.

Избежать модификации ключа можно двумя способами:

1. Клонировать объект в конструкторе Element.
2. Хранить не сам объект Calendar, а его представление в виде long, получаемое с помощью метода getTimeInMillis() (обратное преобразование делается путем создания нового объекта Calendar и вызова у него метода setTimeInMillis())
3. Использовать неизменяемые типы даты из [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)
4. Использовать неизменяемые типы даты из библиотеки [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)